# how to display information from an array using a case statement?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to create a menu based application program that will create an array of 5 instances of the super read initial data for 3 sub classes.

I want to output the details I set for each of the 5 instances from this.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)

    {
Ford myFord = new Ford("no1", "A", 3.2, 2.1, 3.1, 43.4, 9, 10.2);
Ford myFord2 = new Ford ("no2", "B", 1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 43.4, 9, 10.2);    
BMW myBMW = new BMW ("no3", "C", 1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 43.4, 5.0, 100);
BMW myBMW2 = new BMW ("no4", "D", 1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 43.4, 5.0, 100);
Merc myMerc = new Merc ("no5", "E", 1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 43.4, 5.0, 9, "wood");

Car[] myCar = new Car [5];

myCar[0]=myFord;    
myCar[1]=myFord2;   
myCar[2]=myBMW; 
myCar[3]=myBMW2;    
myCar[4]=myMerc;
```

and this is the case statement. im not sure how to output the information using a case.

```
switch(CarNo)
                        {
                            case 1: myCar[0];
                            break;

                            case 2: myCar[1];
                            break;

                            case 3: myCar[2];
                            break;

                            case 4: myCar[3];
                            break;

                            case 5: myCar[4];
                            break;
                        }
```

Comment: This code looks incomplete, and please format the code properly.

Comment: I did not understand what exactly you need

Comment: Apart from the for loop which doesn't appear to be needed, this looks ok.  You could make it shorter, but it should work.  What is the problem you are seeing?

Comment: You could just execute the toString method everywhere and print it

Answer (score 2):

I would remove the loop, unless you need it for some reason you haven't mentioned.  I would also just create the array you need in one go.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    Car[] cars = { new Ford("no1", "A", 3.2, 2.1, 3.1, 43.4, 9, 10.2),
                   new Ford("no2", "B", 1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 43.4, 9, 10.2),
                   new BMW("no3", "C", 1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 43.4, 5.0, 100),
                   new BMW("no4", "D", 1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 43.4, 5.0, 100),
                   new Merc("no5", "E", 1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 43.4, 5.0, 9, "wood") };

    // use the array here e.g.
    for (int i = 0; i < cars.length; i++)
        System.out.printf("%d: %s%n", i, cars[i]);

    String line = Console.readLine("Please select [0-%d] ", cars.length-1);
    int option = Integer.parseInt(line);
    Car car = cars[option];
    System.out.println("You selected a " + car);
```